# Contao CMS gives 404 "Page not found" Error after Installation

Tags: content-management-system, e-commerce, jquery-isotope, contao

I'm facing a problem with an installation of Contao CMS with Isotope e-Commerce. I've followed all steps outlined in the documentation [here](https://docs.contao.org/manual/de/).
But accessing the storefront always leads me to a 404 error as shown.
[image]

I've searched all over the place but couldn't find any solutions to this error. Is there any way to solve this error or am I missing something here?

Comment: Which steps did you follow? Did you follow the necessary steps on creating your first site and page with content within Contao, as outlined in this guide: https://docs.contao.org/manual/en/guides/add-first-index-page/ ?

Comment: I followed the steps from your link for page creation, then added an extension isotope ecommerce. I then created a product category and then some products too. But, how do I make them show up in shop frontend without this error?

Comment: Is your web server able to process `.htaccess` files? The default `.htaccess` contains directives to process any request via the `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, Contao does not set a page start point. You have to define a new starting point in Contao under "Page structure" and ideally map it to the local domain. The first page, e.g. "Home", must then be placed in this starting point.

Example structure from the Contao demo:

[Screenshot Contao Site structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTrB3.png)

Even if the Contao demo is not the most beautiful, you can learn a lot from it: https://demo.contao.org/en/login.html